# Left() & Mid() Function - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to break the string in column `A` in column `C & D` as follows using Left & Mid functions in VBA:

[image]

i have used:

Column C: `Left(Score, (InStr(Score, "-") - 2))`

Column D: `Mid(Score, (InStr(Score, "-")) + 2, (Len(Score)) - ((InStr(Score, "-")) + 1))`

`Score` takes the value of strings in column A

Is there a more efficient - effective way?

Comment: Should not `D2` be equal to `13`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns yes. i ll fix it now

Comment: Anyways, as far as I know, I can't think any way more efficient - effective. My formulas are like yours, except I use `VALUE` to convert it into numbers. That's all. But exactly the same.

Comment: If you are looking for VBA solution then TextToColumns might be one of the best options

Comment: @BrakNicku i store the result of the functions in variables so i think is difficult to use `TextToColumns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If the pattern is Same in Column A, you can use `Split`**

in Column C : `Split(Score, " ")(0)`

in Column D : `Split(Score, " ")(2)`

- You can also save it to a Defined Array, adn can do the split only once.

---

**Alternate 1**

in Column C : `Split(Score, " - ")(0)`

in Column D : `Split(Score, " - ")(1)`

---

**Alternate 2**

`Dim ar() as Variant`

`ar = Split(Score, " - ")`

in Column C : `ar(0)`

in Column D : `ar(1)`

---

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: i preffer to use `Left` and `Mid` because the length of the string in column A differs.

Comment: If the Pattern is same ..i.e `Number ~~ Space~~ - ~~Space ~~Number` then it will produce the correct results, **doesn't matter the length of string** @Error1004

Comment: What is the `(0)` & `(2)` outside the brackets of `Split`?

Comment: `(0)` will give you the first result of the Split, likewise `(2)` will give you the 3rd Result. And as for a fact the string will always be splitted in 3 if the pattern remains the same.

Comment: Why don't you just split on `" - "`. Furthermore a fine solution :)

Comment: i want to avoid getting spaces in my result, that s why i try to avoid `split`

Comment: You will not get any spaces in your result. You can use `Trim` for that , while printing the Result. @Error1004

Comment: @Error1004, then use `TRIM(Split(Score, " - ")(0))` to be a 100% sure. Not that it would matter in this particular case I believe.

Comment: I did not know at all that you could already use an index of an array right inmediately after splitting. I mean i did not know about `(0)` and `(2)` applied directly after `Split`. Awesome. Upvoted.